# How is freed an app when swiped from recent tasks with C++Builder

Tags: android, c++, memory-leaks, c++builder

My android application has two ways to close.
One is to call `Application->Terminate();` which is supposed to close the `Application->MainForm` and shutdown the application in an orderly fashion.
The other is to swipe the app from recent tasks.

By using the first way, I can see in my logs the log of my `ClosingForm`, but I don't see the closing log of my `MainForm`.

The second way seems to never calls any `FormClose` method, and there is no log remaining of Forms closing by swiping the app. I fear this leads to many memory leakage in my app.

Is there any way to catch the event of an app being swiped of recent tasks to prevent memory leakage ?

```
void __fastcall ClosingForm::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
        Global->addToLog("Close Form Closing app");
        Action = TCloseAction::caFree;
        Application->Terminate();
}

void __fastcall MainForm::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
        Global->addToLog("Main Form Closing");
        //freeing objects 
        delete Global;
        delete otherObjets; 
        Action = TCloseAction::caFree;
}
```

Comment: Android can terminate your app at any time when it is not the foreground app.  It does this by killing the process.  Swiping-off is an end-user action that can force the above termination.  Your code needs to expect that after you have stopped being the foreground task your process can be killed at any time. eg saving on the onPause event.  See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Addendum: _"..to prevent memory leakage..."_  your process has been killed so memory cannot leak.

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh, so this post for example applies to Android as well ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275184/when-interrupting-a-process-does-a-memory-leak-occur?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: So the memory is still reusable if the process is killed, but I still don't understand why the `FormClose` method of my `MainForm` seems to not be called (not executing the code in the destrcutors of my objects to free as I'd like it to do) when `Application->Terminate();` is called.

Comment: Because the Android kernel just terminates your process, no API calls, no call-backs.  It's a mobile phone operating system, so if for example, it needs the memory to answer a phone call your process will be killed to make resources available.  See the Application Lifecycle link above and follow the left path from `onStop()`.

Comment: Retrieve FMX's [`IFMXApplicationEventService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationEventService) interface and call its [`SetApplicationEventHandler()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler) method to receive [system events](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.TApplicationEvent), like `EnteredBackground`, `WillBecomeInactive`, `WillTerminate`, etc

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I've already implemented that to disconnect and connect my scan module. Sadly as richard says it seems I can't get the WillTerminate event when the app is swiped. Seems like I should serialize my objects and delete them at every EnteredBackground event and Deserialize them back on WillBecomeForeground.